# Tkinter's asksaveasfilename randomly ignores defaultextension

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

Has anyone using Python/Tkinter's `asksaveasfilename` dialog seen cases where it randomly "forgets" the `defaultextension` parameter and defaults to the last element in your 'filetypes' list?

I.e., given this below example code:

```
options = {}
options['defaultextension'] = ".foo"
options['filetypes'] = (("Foo files", ".foo"), ("Bar files", ".bar"), ("All files", "*"))
options['initialdir'] = ""
options['initialfile'] = ""
options['title'] = "Save as..."

outfile = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename(**options)
```

While my application is running, there are times where the "Save As" dialog will, when it is invoked, just stop using the value passed in the `defaultextension` and start using the "All files" item, which is the last item in the tuple passed to `filetypes`.  The `options` dict is a local variable that is built every time the definition is called, so this should not be happening.  I have to close and restart my app to get the expected behavior back.

I've tried timing it, seeing if it's a certain number of invocations of `asksaveasfilename`, etc, but I cannot find a trigger.  I am suspecting that this is a bug in Python or Tk, but would like to know if anyone else has seen this before I go creating a bug.  I cannot reproduce this behavior with the Open dialog.

Witnessing this on Python 2.7.6 and earlier, with tk-8.5.15 (I think -- using Portable Python w/ PyScripter).

Comment: When "All files" is selected, are the other options still in the listbox or is it the only option? And if the other options are there, in which order are they?

Comment: All of the filetype options are in the combobox when this happens.  It just seems that once this "bug" occurs, any further calls to `asksaveasfilename` always default to "All files", which for me, is always the last item in the list.  Lists are supposed to be ordered, so it seems to me like Tkinter/Python is still keeping an object reference around and not fully re-initializing the dropdown box, and somehow, picks the last item in the list.  Just an observation/first guess w/o debugging any.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the `defaultextension` option does what you think it does.

From [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/getOpenFile.htm):

> -defaultextension extension
>
> Specifies a string that will be appended to the filename if the user enters a filename without an extension. The default value is the empty string, which means no extension will be appended to the filename in any case.

So the `defaultextension` only adds a default extension if no extension is specified by the user and has no effect on which filetype is selected. In your example this is only the case when 'All files' is selected and the user types in only a name without extension.

As far as I know the filetypes should be in the listbox in the same order in which they are in the `filetypes` tuple. And for all the quick tests I've done, they are.

Comment: I thought this also controlled the default filter in the `filetypes` list.  IF not, then the issue would seem to suggest that something in Tkinter/Python is randomly switching from picking the first item in the list to picking the last item.

Answer (score 0):

File dialog behavior is different on OSX and other systems.  Idle 3.4.2+ currently has the following code in idlelib/IOBindings.py.

```
filetypes = [
    ("Python files", "*.py *.pyw", "TEXT"),
    ("Text files", "*.txt", "TEXT"),
    ("All files", "*"),
    ]

defaultextension = '.py' if sys.platform == 'darwin' else ''

def asksavefile(self):
    dir, base = self.defaultfilename("save")
    if not self.savedialog:
        self.savedialog = tkFileDialog.SaveAs(
                master=self.text,
                filetypes=self.filetypes,
                defaultextension=self.defaultextension)
    filename = self.savedialog.show(initialdir=dir, initialfile=base)
    return filename
```

On Windows and, I believe, linux, .py, .txt, or nothing  are automatically added according to the file type selected (with defaultextension = '').  Only OSX, the same would result in no added extension, so we use an explicit .py.  I am not sure if .py is always added or just when Python files is selected.  (Only filetypes is used for open).

PS. Before filing a bug report on the CPython tracker, please test with the latest patch release and include system.  For tkinter/idle, run you code from a console that can receive tcl error messages.

Comment: I have only seen this issue on Windows 7 so far.  I've done very little testing in Linux (and don't really plan to -- current app is Windows only for now), and 1 test in OS X when I got access to such a machine.  App looks great in Windows, and looked like crap in Aqua, so I forced it to the standard Unix widget set and have ignored that platform for now.